# Copy-and-paste of mathematical formulas pastes the unformatted, raw TeX

Tags: lyx, copy-paste

For instance:

1. Copy [image]
2. Paste in a new location
3. Result: x^{2}

LyX 2.0.4 (new)/MiKTeX/Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit

Comment: I assume that you consider this a problem, and that you would like the formatted version instead. Where are you pasting it to?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Your assumptions are correct. I paste it to the same document.

Comment: I wish PDFs worked like that :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are copying within LyX math-mode, you are in fact copying the raw TeX. Simply create a new equation using Ctrl-M (or whatever you've bound it to be) and then paste.

Unfortunately, there is no good way around this problem internally without significant changes to the program logic.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is: i usually copy-and-paste not single formulas, but whole paragraphs containing many formulas. Am i doomed?

Comment: There might be an easy way around that in the program logic, actually. Unfortunately, it's more a feature request than some problem to be fixed.

Comment: In a WYSIWYG editor i'd consider it a critical bug.

Comment: There is a good argument for either. WYSIWYG should be innately intuitive, and all environments that are encompassed in a selection should carry with their environments.

Comment: I do not have LyX installed at the moment, but I seem to remember that you can select the TeX formula, press Ctrl-M, and it will convert it into math.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts > Cursor, Mouse and Editing...
Now remove the shortcut for `paste` which is set as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Now go to `selection-paste` in the same list, click Modify and set as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thx, this solved the issue for me. I also remapped the normal `paste` to another key, thus I can easily copy plain-TeX.

Answer (score 1):

If you mark inside the math block, you have to paste into another math block. Otherwise you would resolve the math TeX-Code into your normal text.

You may also mark the block and surronding normal text and paste it somewhere else. As of LyX 2.0.4 on my old windows machine in the office, this does not always work. After restarting LyX, it usually works. On linux, I have not encountered this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using LyX 2.0.6/MiKTeX on Windows, and have experienced the same problem - a copy and paste of an equation pastes the literal equation text instead of the equation. Even worse, it strips out any labels in the process. For figure floats, I don't get anything at all when I paste. This can make editing and re-arranging text problematic.

However, this appears to be a matter of some bad internal program state (I don't know how to reproduce it yet). Most of the time, copy and paste work as intuitively expected. The best work around is to close and re-open LyX with the same document. This restores the appropriate behavior for me.